# Flash player keeps crashing in all browsers

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, windows-vista, crash, flash

Whenever i try to watch a video using flash player the flash player crashes. Sometimes ti playes a couple of second of the video but will crash after them sometimes it just crashes right away. I tried using flash player in firefox and in Chrome both having the flash player stopped responding window popping up. I am using windows vista x64 and this is happening on the newest version of flash `(11.7.700.202)`. I tried restarting the computer and reinstalling the flash player they did not solve my problems. I tried turning of the hardware acceleration in the browser options but it did not fix anything.

Anybody has any idea of what is going on? 
Maybe i could install an older version of flash as a temporary fix? Although im not even sure how i could do that.

I also restarted firefox in safe mode so all my addons were disabled it did not fix the problem

Comment: ok after i restarted the computer the problem fixed itself for a brief moment although it is still choppy just as i start the video. I dont understand what is happening :/

Comment: It keeps braking soon after each restart.

Comment: well after a along while the problem has fixed itself. I think it might have been an error in the flash program itself.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a crash problem in firefox and mute sound in chrome with flash.
Problem is due to the frequency in sound card manager : maximum is 192kHz. My sound card allows to have 384kHz, and with this option, flash constantly crash in browsers.
Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 18 & 20 do have a current flash bug. Chrome should work fine though. It has inbuilt flash, independent of Firefox's flash.Try to disable flash in Chrome with `chrome://plugins/`- if it still crashes- it's not flash. Also, sometimes extensions may crash it (Adblock, Flashblock and IDM being the main culprits)

OPTIONS:
1. you might want to revert to a more stable build of Firefox
2. use html5 for viewing videos (all major sites support it)

sources : [Mozilla forums](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/956651)

Comment: i did disable flash in both browsers and they do not crash. They only crash when the video plays and both browsers do that not just firefox. Also if you read the question i state that i disabled all my extensions while running the browsers

Answer (score 0):

You might need to find flash version that is appropriate in your OS. It can be the reason why your flash player crash. You can go to this link to find your appropriate flash version.

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html

Comment: thanks i already did that. Sadly i do have the appropriate flash version.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.